# Simulate the Commitment of a DirectoryEntry (AD-UserAccount)

Tags: c#, directoryservices

I have developed an application, that automatically creates Active Directory User Accounts, definied by an extern datasource. The Project is almost completed and tested and the application works fine.

But now, as part of a further Project, the application should additionally be able to simulate the creation/editing of AD-Acounts. The whole process should be completed except the final commitment of the DirectoryEntry to the AD, so that you can see, what would be done by the application. There have to be lots of tests successfully completed to the data from the extern datasource, before an AD-Account will be created.

But instead of easily not committing the DirectoryEntry, I finally would like to let the Active Directory verify the correctness of the DirectoryEntry instead of creating/editing an account.

The target is, to make the simulation as much realistic as possible, because in spite of all tests where successfully completed, we had situations, where the AD refused the creation of AD-Accounts.

Our Active Directory is very complex and consist of several domains with lots of restrictions, so a Simulation and documentation of all changes, that would be done by the application would be useful.
It would be possible  to create an AD-Account and delete it instantly but this would cause Problems with the replication in circumstances, so I will avoid that.

Does anyone knows, how to do such a Simulation in C#?

Comment: You're not doing *simulation*. Simulating it would mean not actually talking to AD at all. You're doing integration testing. If possible you should set up a mirrored AD system for test purposes and test against that. If you can't do that, you need to do exactly what you don't want to, actually go ahead and try to create the account and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I guess, Setting up a mirrored AD System is not possible. 
Testing in a specified area in the AD should be possible, but my main Point of interrest is to check, if certain changes to existing accounts are possible. I had the hope that there is an api in AD for that.